# How convert sentences to column/row of single words

Tags: excel, vba

Why is it not working?

Prints only the first word and I don't know how I can change "10" in "For" on something like "For each word in sentence"

```
 Sub Change()
    Dim S As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim x As String
    
    
    S = InputBox("Sentence")
    x = Split(S, " ")
For i = 1 To x
 Cells(1, i).Value = Split(S, " ")
 
 Next i
  
End Sub
```

Comment: `Split` first, then loop the array result from `Split`.

Comment: @BigBen Something like this? But still is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Sub Change()
    Dim sentence As String: sentence = InputBox("Sentence")
    Dim col As Long: col = 1
    Dim word As Variant: For Each word In Split(sentence, " ")
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, col).Value = word
        col = col + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Split Sentence to Worksheet

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SentenceToRow()
    Const ProcTitle As String = "Sentence to Row"
    Const First As String = "A1"
    
    Dim S As Variant: S = InputBox("Input a Sentence", ProcTitle)
    If Len(S) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You canceled.", vbExclamation, ProcTitle
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim Strings() As String: Strings = Split(S)
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = UBound(Strings) + 1
        
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range(First).Resize(, cCount)
    rg.Value = Strings
    
    MsgBox "Sentence split to a row.", vbInformation, ProcTitle

End Sub

Sub SentenceToColumn()
    Const ProcTitle As String = "Sentence to Column"
    Const First As String = "A1"
    
    Dim S As Variant: S = InputBox("Input a Sentence", ProcTitle)
    If Len(S) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You canceled.", vbExclamation, ProcTitle
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim Strings() As String: Strings = Split(S)
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = UBound(Strings) + 1
        
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range(First).Resize(rCount)
    rg.Value = Application.Transpose(Strings)
    
    MsgBox "Sentence split to a column.", vbInformation, ProcTitle

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

this is fast and eficient:

```
Sub testSplit2Row()
    Dim frase As String
    frase = "las palabras de amor"
    
    Dim ary As Variant
    ary = Split(frase, " ")
    
    Dim dest As Range
    Dim start As Range
    Set start = Range("B1")
    Set dest = start.Resize(UBound(ary) + 1)
    dest.Value = Application.Transpose(ary)
    
    start.Resize(, UBound(ary) + 1).Value = ary
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dispose of the dynamic array functions of *MSExcel 365*, you might profit from the following function, usable as well as *udf* or via *code*.

The function `words()` accepts range values, array values or explicit string inputs as first argument `s`; the second argument `IsVertical` is *optional* and indicates that results will be returned as vertical array by *default* (instead of a "flat" array).

```
Public Function words(ByVal s As Variant, Optional IsVertical As Boolean = True)
    'Debug.Print VarType(s)
    If VarType(s) >= vbArray Then
        s = Replace(Application.WorksheetFunction.ArrayToText(s), ",", "")
    End If
    words = Split(s)
    If IsVertical Then
        words = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Split(s))
    End If
End Function
```

**a) Example using a multi-row range input in `B2`**

```
   =words(A2:A4)
```

[image: udf]

**b) Example call via code**

```
Option Explicit                         ' module head of code module 

Sub ExampleCall
    With Sheet1
        Dim wds As Variant
        wds = words(.Range("A2:A4"))
        .Range("A10").Resize(UBound(wds), UBound(wds, 2)) = wds
    End With
End Sub
```

If you intend, however to display results horizontally, just code as follows *(note the dimension change!)*:

```
    '...
    wds = words(.Range("a2:a4"), False)         ' False returns "flat" 1-dim array
    .Range("A10").Resize(1, UBound(wds)) = wds
```